# GZIP process takes CPU usage 100%

Tags: cpu, gzip

[image]

GZIP uses 100% of the CPU.

I tried using `pstree -apl` to get which processes needed the GZIP, and I found Logratate.

Have some people experienced this? And how did you solve it?

Comment: Try reducing priority with "nice" command maybe.

Comment: at least you're not paying for ram you don't use 

Comment: Yes, `gzip` typically uses 100% of 1 CPU, I have never had to "solve" it, because I have many CPUs.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, all.

Comment: I'm running out of spaces this morrrrrrrrnning... It turns out that the kern.log and sys.log growth This has the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/71604479 and [the solution](https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/).